# TempDB is not releasing space on restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I'm facing any issue related to tempDB on one of my production database.
Usually, tempDB is releasing space when we restart the SQL Server. But, in my productionDB when i restart the server, tempDB is not releasing space.It had 48 GB before restart and after restart it had same size.
Please help me, what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

After restart ,TEMPDB default size will be reset to the size which was last modified..so expecting to reduce beyond 48 GB wont happen in your case..

To check TempdB size use below query..

```
SELECT SUM(size)*1.0/128 AS [Tempdb size in MB]
FROM tempdb.sys.database_files
```

Further restarting TEMPDB everytime to release space is a bad practice.You will need to troubleshoot to see which queries are filling TEMPDB and why they are not releasing space..

Comment: Thanks. I have executed this query, it is showing 19.5000 MB but i already been shrink the TempDB.

Comment: What i meant was TEMPDB will release all the space used and will reset to the last modified size after reset.So run some operations which uses tempdb,run the query i gave and see the difference after restart

Comment: Hey! I have restarted the SQL Server. Now Before the restart it has 19 MB and after Restart size is same.